# Tried to open a file correctly but keep getting errn2, why?

Tags: python

I want to open a file For this exercise as such:

you will first write a function create2dlistbooks(file_name) that opens the file, reads it and returns a 2D lists containing a sublist with the info about each book.

Here's what I did:

```
def createbooks2Dlist(file_name):
     doc = open(file_name).read().splitlines()

     list2Dlist = []
     for i in doc:
          i = i.split("\n")
          title = i[0]
          author = i[1]
          publisher = i[2]
          date = i[3]
          date = date.split("/")
          if len(date[0]) == 1:
                            day = "0" + date[0]
          else:
               day = date[0]
          if len(date[1]) == 1:
               month = "0" + date[1]
          else:
               month = date[1]

          year = date[2]
          final_date = year + '-' + day + '-' + month
          date = final_date

          bookgenre = i[4].strip()
          list2Dlist.append([date,name,author,publisherbookgenre])

     return list2Dlist

books = createbooks2Dlist("NYT_short.txt)
print(books)
```

However, here's what shows up :

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'NYT_short.txt'

Why ??? and how can I correct this please

Comment: it would help to see the structure and perhaps extension of the file

Comment: Did you run your script in the directory where the file is stored ?

Comment: Try to pass the complete path for the file to the function.

Comment: This is more of a path issue. If you are on windows, try to pass the entire absolute path starting with C:\ or similar to that. Same goes if you are in linux.

Comment: @Anton, the file structure is not needed here. The problem is related with the file path and not its contents.

Comment: Your filename is missing a closing double quote. It should be `"NYT_short.txt"` but you have `"NYT_short.txt`

Comment: Sembei, still won't work after that change

Comment: What do you mean by file path ?

Comment: @COCO2122 where is this .py file located?